# MySQL Lookup Nearest or Exact Matching Value With Changing Lookup Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following sets of data...

**Condition Monitoring Location Data (CML Table)**

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+-------+-----+
| CML_ID |     POF_COLUMN     |      CML_TYPE      | SAMPLE_VALUE | COMPLIANCE | CORROSION_SEVERITY | LR_LD | POF |
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+-------+-----+
|      1 | SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT |            5 | NO         | MINOR              |     1 |     |
|      2 | SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT |          0.5 | NO         | MINOR              |     2 |     |
|      3 | SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT |           20 | NO         | MINOR              |     3 |     |
|      4 | COMPLIANCE         | VALVE_ROTATED      |            0 | YES        | MINOR              |     4 |     |
|      5 | LR_LD              | PIPING_THICKNESS   |            0 | YES        | MINOR              |   0.1 |     |
|      6 | CORROSION_SEVERITY | VESSEL_SHELL       |            0 | NO         | SEVERE             |     0 |     |
|      7 | CORROSION_SEVERITY | NOZZLE             |            0 | NO         | LOW                |     0 |     |
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+-------+-----+
```

**Probability of Failure Lookup Data (POF Table)**

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+-----+
|     POF_COLUMN     |      CML_TYPE      | VALUE_RANGE | POF |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+-----+
| SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT | 1           |   5 |
| SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT | 5           |   4 |
| SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT | 10          |   3 |
| SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT | 15          |   2 |
| SAMPLE_VALUE       | MIC_SAMPLING_POINT | 100         |   1 |
| COMPLIANCE         | VALVE_ROTATED      | YES         |   5 |
| COMPLIANCE         | VALVE_ROTATED      | NO          |   1 |
| LR_LD              | PIPING_THICKNESS   | 2           |   5 |
| LR_LD              | PIPING_THICKNESS   | 1.5         |   4 |
| LR_LD              | PIPING_THICKNESS   | 1           |   3 |
| LR_LD              | PIPING_THICKNESS   | 0.8         |   2 |
| LR_LD              | PIPING_THICKNESS   | 0.5         |   1 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | VESSEL_SHELL       | NEGLIGIBLE  |   5 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | VESSEL_SHELL       | LOW         |   4 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | VESSEL_SHELL       | MEDIUM      |   3 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | VESSEL_SHELL       | HIGH        |   2 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | VESSEL_SHELL       | SEVERE      |   1 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | NOZZLE             | NEGLIGIBLE  |   5 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | NOZZLE             | LOW         |   5 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | NOZZLE             | MEDIUM      |   5 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | NOZZLE             | HIGH        |   3 |
| CORROSION_SEVERITY | NOZZLE             | SEVERE      |   2 |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+-----+
```

And I need to return the closet or exactly matching record in the POF Table using the [POF_Column], [CML_Type] and either the [SAMPLE_VALUE], [COMPLIANCE], [CORROSION_SEVERITY] or [LR_LD] fields for each CML record in the CML Table. Then update that records POF to the CML table.

For example if we look at CML_ID = 2.

Filter the POF table by [POF_COLUMN] = 'SAMPLE_VALUE', [CML_TYPE] = 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT' And [VALUE_RANGE] - Value in the [SAMPLE_VALUE] Column (in this case 0.5) is a minimum.

In this case it would match this first record in the POF table and return a value of POF = 5.

If we look at another case. CML_ID = 7.

Filter the POF table by [POF_COLUMN] = 'CORROSION_SEVERITY', [CML_TYPE] = 'NOZZLE' And [VALUE_RANGE] = Value in the [CORROSION_SEVERITY] Column, in this case 'LOW'.

In this case it would match the forth row from the bottom in the POF table and return a value of POF = 5.

In summary I need UPDATE the CML table to show the following results...

```
+--------+---+-----+
| CML_ID | … | POF |
+--------+---+-----+
|      1 | … |   4 |
|      2 | … |   5 |
|      3 | … |   2 |
|      4 | … |   5 |
|      5 | … |   1 |
|      6 | … |   1 |
|      7 | … |   5 |
+--------+---+-----+
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I have placed some sample code of my attempts at this below. Which works for looking up exact matching values but not closest matching values.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS VESSELS;
CREATE DATABASE VESSELS;
USE VESSELS;

CREATE TABLE CML (
  `CML_ID`              INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `POF_COLUMN`          VARCHAR(50),
  `CML_TYPE`            VARCHAR(50),
  `SAMPLE_VALUE`        FLOAT,
  `COMPLIANCE`          ENUM('YES','NO'),
  `CORROSION_SEVERITY`  VARCHAR(50),
  `LR_LD`               FLOAT,
  `POF`                 TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (CML_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE POF (
  `POF_COLUMN`   VARCHAR(50),
  `CML_TYPE`     VARCHAR(50),
  `VALUE_RANGE`  VARCHAR(100),
  `POF`          TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (POF_COLUMN, CML_TYPE, VALUE_RANGE)
);

INSERT INTO CML 
VALUES (1, 'SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 5, 'NO', 'MINOR', 1, NULL),
       (2, 'SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 0.5, 'NO', 'MINOR', 2, NULL),
       (3, 'SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 20, 'NO', 'MINOR', 3, NULL), 
       (4, 'COMPLIANCE', 'VALVE_ROTATED', 0, 'YES', 'MINOR', 4, NULL), 
       (5, 'LR_LD', 'PIPING_THICKNESS', 0, 'YES', 'MINOR', 0.1, NULL),
       (6, 'CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'VESSEL_SHELL', 0, 'NO', 'SEVERE', 0, NULL),
       (7, 'CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'NOZZLE', 0, 'NO', 'LOW', 0, NULL);

INSERT INTO POF 
VALUES ('SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 1, 5),
       ('SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 5, 4),
       ('SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 10, 3),
       ('SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 15, 2),
       ('SAMPLE_VALUE', 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT', 100, 1),
       ('COMPLIANCE', 'VALVE_ROTATED', 'YES', 5), 
       ('COMPLIANCE', 'VALVE_ROTATED', 'NO', 1), 
       ('LR_LD', 'PIPING_THICKNESS', 2, 5),
       ('LR_LD', 'PIPING_THICKNESS', 1.5, 4),
       ('LR_LD', 'PIPING_THICKNESS', 1, 3),
       ('LR_LD', 'PIPING_THICKNESS', 0.8, 2),
       ('LR_LD', 'PIPING_THICKNESS', 0.5, 1),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'VESSEL_SHELL', 'NEGLIGIBLE', 5),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'VESSEL_SHELL', 'LOW', 4),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'VESSEL_SHELL', 'MEDIUM', 3),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'VESSEL_SHELL', 'HIGH', 2),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'VESSEL_SHELL', 'SEVERE', 1),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'NOZZLE', 'NEGLIGIBLE', 5),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'NOZZLE', 'LOW', 5),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'NOZZLE', 'MEDIUM', 5),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'NOZZLE', 'HIGH', 3),
       ('CORROSION_SEVERITY', 'NOZZLE', 'SEVERE', 2);

-- UPDATE EXACT MATCHING VALUE
UPDATE CML c
LEFT JOIN POF p
ON c.POF_COLUMN = p.POF_COLUMN
   AND c.CML_TYPE = p.CML_TYPE
   AND ( (c.POF_COLUMN = 'COMPLIANCE' AND c.COMPLIANCE = p.VALUE_RANGE) OR
         (c.POF_COLUMN = 'SAMPLE_VALUE' AND c.SAMPLE_VALUE = p.VALUE_RANGE) OR
         (c.POF_COLUMN = 'LR_LD' AND c.LR_LD = p.VALUE_RANGE) OR
         (c.POF_COLUMN = 'CORROSION_SEVERITY' AND c.CORROSION_SEVERITY = p.VALUE_RANGE)
       )
SET c.POF = p.POF;

SELECT * FROM CML;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upvote for a very detailed post with sample data and expected result. 
The problem lies on sample_value and lr_ld since it will may not be the exact value from POF table. However, you will notice that the values are either equal or less than the value range.

Therefore, if we get the max value of POF value wherein sample_value or lr_ld is less than or equal to value range, then we only need to get max of POF value.

**This query will only work since the POF value increases when sample_value or lr_ld increases.**

```
UPDATE CML c
  JOIN 
(
    select c.CML_ID, max(p.POF) POF 
    from CML c
    LEFT JOIN POF p
    ON c.POF_COLUMN = p.POF_COLUMN
       AND c.CML_TYPE = p.CML_TYPE
       AND ( (c.POF_COLUMN = 'COMPLIANCE' AND c.COMPLIANCE = p.VALUE_RANGE) OR
             (c.POF_COLUMN = 'SAMPLE_VALUE' AND  c.SAMPLE_VALUE<=p.VALUE_RANGE) OR
             (c.POF_COLUMN = 'LR_LD' AND c.LR_LD  <= p.VALUE_RANGE) OR
             (c.POF_COLUMN = 'CORROSION_SEVERITY' AND c.CORROSION_SEVERITY = p.VALUE_RANGE)
           )
     group by c.CML_ID 
   ) t
 on c.CML_ID = t.CML_ID
set c.POF = t.POF;
```

Comment: thanks this gave me the hint I needed to come up with a final result that matches my records on either the exact matching or closest matching value for the primary key (POF_COLUMN, CML_TYPE and VALUE_RANGE) in the POF table. See my final solution in the fiddle link provided. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eeb9b/1

Comment: Can you check cml id =3? It should be 1 isnt?

Comment: Nope should definately be 2. SAMPLE_VALUE =  20, Closest matching value in POF table is 15. Therefore POF is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Nicely phrased question, with enough detail.

You have a challenge here.

A) The value in POF is either a string or a float.  When it's a string, you need to do an exact comparison.  If it's a float, you want to find the closest value.

This screams business code in an application server, but let's assume that you want to do it in MySQL.

The answer is a case statement that determines, by CML_TYPE, how to calculate the POF.  For "string" type comparisons, this would be an equals.  For "float" type comparisons, you'll can write the comparison to get the record closest to the supplied value.  Either way, each of the rules is slightly different.

What you'll need to do is create a CASE statement for each CML_TYPE and then create a custom matcher to find the POF that you want.

The following code actually works, but there is no guarantee about performance.

```
UPDATE CML c
  JOIN 
(select CML_ID, 
  CASE CML_TYPE 
     WHEN 'VALVE_ROTATED' THEN
       (select POF from POF where POF.CML_TYPE = CML.CML_TYPE and VALUE_RANGE = CML.COMPLIANCE)
     WHEN 'VESSEL_SHELL' THEN
       (select POF from POF where POF.CML_TYPE = CML.CML_TYPE and VALUE_RANGE = CML.CORROSION_SEVERITY)
     WHEN 'NOZZLE' THEN
       (select POF from POF where POF.CML_TYPE = CML.CML_TYPE and VALUE_RANGE = CML.CORROSION_SEVERITY)
     WHEN 'MIC_SAMPLING_POINT' THEN
       (select POF from POF where POF.CML_TYPE = CML.CML_TYPE ORDER BY ABS(CML.SAMPLE_VALUE - cast(VALUE_RANGE AS DECIMAL(10,2))) LIMIT 1)
     WHEN 'PIPING_THICKNESS' THEN
       (select POF from POF where POF.CML_TYPE = CML.CML_TYPE ORDER BY ABS(CML.SAMPLE_VALUE - cast(VALUE_RANGE AS DECIMAL(10,2))) LIMIT 1)
     ELSE 'BLAH'       
  END as CALC_POF
from CML) as updater on c.CML_ID = updater.CML_ID
set c.POF = updater.CALC_POF;
```

[Link TO SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/662adf/1)

Comment: @Brain thanks for the answer. As you say, this does work, but I dont really want to use correlated subqueries in the UPDATE statement. I managed to come up with a solution (see comment to annoyXmous' answer below) which does what I need. Thanks for your answer which gave me some helpful hints to come up with my final solution!